# Why does the UH-1 Huey have a hump at the rear of the cabin?

Tags: helicopter, feature-identification, cabin-design, cabin, bell-uh-1

Why does the [Huey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_UH-1_Iroquois) have this weird hump as shown in the picture? For some system? Why not remove it?

[image: https://www.helis.com/h2/uh-1h_seats.jpg]
<sup>https://www.helis.com/h2/uh-1h_seats.jpg</sup>

Comment: Because the main rotor shaft and associated equipment (gearboxes) does not end at the outer fuselage skin. I am sure someone more versed in the arcane version numbers of the UH-1 will be able to weigh in regarding when the area around that "hump" was made available.

Comment: @AEheresupportsMonica Comments are not for providing partial answers.

Answer (score 4):

[image: pinterest scale model pic]
A copy of the original image can be found [here](http://i6.photobucket.com/albums/y211/intruder_bass/9-1.jpg), which is about 5 'pagedowns' down [this page](http://cs.finescale.com/fsm/modeling_subjects/f/16/t/75405.aspx?sortorder=desc&page=15), which has a number of other excellent Huey-model photos.

It's a bit of structure to guide the rotor forces into the rest of the airframe, it would not be good if this bit went missing.

Fwd/aft, left/right, up/down. The rotor provides the lifting forces and driving forces and these are quite concentrated around the rotor axis. Picture the airframe like an empty beer can - some panels are required to cope with the forces while remaining in shape.

Comment: Nice model. Yours?

Comment: @Freeman found it while searching for a structural image for the Huey, seems to be unclear if the original site still exists. Could not find a clear reference address for it.

Comment: Providing a source for the image would be strongly recommended, then.

Answer (score 3):

It's where the main rotor transmission and control servos are housed. The forward bulkhead of the "hump" WAS the entire aft cabin bulkhead of the original Huey models. Starting with the D model (I Think) the cabin was extended around the transmission tunnel to form what are called the right and left alcoves. The original shorter body Hueys were adapted to the gunship roles.